# How can i render a very big SVG file in HTML5?

Tags: html, svg

I have recently wanted to create something similar to this on my own: http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/

It is basically a map of zipcodes for the United States. Currently, i have thousands of points that compose the Zip Code boundaries. With these coordinates, I created a KML file. However, it seems that the file is way too big (32MB) When i render it on the browser, it takes a long time to load and it looks very bury. 
What approach should i take to make it faster?

What i want to do is to be able to see a map of all the zipcode areas in the United States. I should use SVG or Canvas.  I chose to use SVG: http://danilocarrion.com/Map.html

Please let me know if there is a way to make it faster, sharper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki), a tutorial and some instructions can be found [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Comment: Thank you Erik. My goal is to use the KML file that i already have. What you provided me does not make use of KML. I will check out topojson.

Comment: Not sure if there are any direct KML -> TopoJSON converters, but you can find converters from KML -> GeoJSON, and converters from GeoJSON -> TopoJSON.